# createQueryBuilder / Join Column - Symfony

Tags: php, mysql, left-join, symfony

I have a trouble to implement this SQL Request :

```
SELECT *
FROM project
LEFT JOIN user 
ON project.idAuthor=user.id 
WHERE project.isVisible = 1 AND
user.role = 'agency'
```

To a simple Symfony Query Builder :

```
 $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
            ->leftJoin('WebAwardsBundle:User', 'u')
            ->where('p.isVisible = 1')
            ->andwhere("u.role = 'agency'")
            ->orderBy('p.id', 'DESC')
            ->getQuery();
```

The response of this query give me all the project, include the project when role !== agency ...

I don't know where I can put the `ON project.idAuthor=user.id`

Mapping :

Project :

```
    /**
 * Project
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="project")
 *@ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="WebAwardsBundle\Repostory\ProjectRepository")
 */
class Project
{
    ...
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="projects")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="idAuthor", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $idAuthor;

...
```

User :

```
/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="WebAwardsBundle\Repository\UserRepository")
 */
class User implements UserInterface, \Serializable{

...

 /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Project", mappedBy="idAuthor")
     */
    private $projects;
...
```

Comment: It's a left join, so yes, it will still bring back all rows from `p`. As for the `ON` part, you've defined the relationship in the entity (or other documented place), so you don't need to explicitly provide it.

Comment: Have you looked at the docs?  Hint: You don't need an ON clause for doctrine query builder.  The query builder already knows how your relations are mapped.

Comment: If you don't want to have the projects where user.role !== agency, then you should use `innerJoin`.

Comment: @EmanuelOster : Sorry, the `innerJoin` doesn't give me only the agency :/

Comment: @Cerad : mmmokay, I saw this, but I think my mapped is al ready fine ... I'll post that.

Comment: I'm sure your mapping is fine.  That is not the point.  Lookup an example of how to use leftJoin in a doctrine query.  Just don't hurt yourself with the resulting face palm.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer to implement this SQL Request :

```
SELECT *
FROM project
LEFT JOIN user 
ON project.idAuthor=user.id 
WHERE project.isVisible = 1 AND
user.role = 'agency'
```

is to join the correct column of the entity (project.idAuthor to user in this case) :

```
$query = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
        ->join('p.idAuthor', 'u')
        ->where('p.isVisible = 1')
        ->andWhere("u.role = 'agency'")
        ->orderBy('p.id', 'DESC')
        ->getQuery();
```